# Ninject's NinjectHttpModule causing ASP.NET databound controls to lose data

Tags: .net, ninject, webforms

In my ASP.NET WebForms (3.5) application, adding the `NinjectHttpModule` to the `<httpModules>` section in the web config causes repeaters and listviews to lose their databound items on postback.

A bit of Googling showed that some others were [experiencing the same issue](http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/aed65936d88152d4/4dbac592bcb9403c?#4dbac592bcb9403c) but it none of their solutions are working for me.

I'm using `Ninject.Web.MasterPageBase` for my master pages and `Ninject.Web.PageBase` for all my pages. I'm also using the `UserControlBase` mentioned in the post I linked.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty alarming.  Can't imagine how `NinjectHttpModule` is written such that it silently breaks code like this without throwing any errors.  Good question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web/issues/1

[ASP.NET dynamic data: Table is not shown anymore after inserting data if FormView.Controls is accessed on Page.Initialized event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360989/asp-net-dynamic-data-table-is-not-shown-anymore-after-inserting-data-if-formview)